# Set the font size and color of an AmChart4 XYCursor's X and Y label

Tags: amcharts4

I've looked here:
https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/xycursor/

and tried this

```
chart.cursor.fontSize = "14";
chart.cursor.fill = am4core.color("#ff0000");
chart.cursor.fontFamily = "verdana";
```

To style the (default white on black) element when the xycursor touches the X/Y axis (don't know what the correct name for this element is, hope you know which one I mean)

I would like to set the font size and family. Tried to set the color to `red` to see if it has to be set via the fill property, but also that doesn't work.

Created the cursor like this:

```
 chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
    chart.cursor.xAxis = axis;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the tooltip properties inside the axis objects directly, [as mentioned in the documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/axis-tooltips/#Modifying_tooltip_appearance). For example, to change the font, size and color in the category axis tooltip, modify the tooltip's label object:

```
categoryAxis.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false; 
categoryAxis.tooltip.label.fill = "#ff0000"
categoryAxis.tooltip.label.fontFamily = "Courier New"
categoryAxis.tooltip.label.fontSize = 15;
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/4209407c88ae67e702d0b8ce46e3a937?editors=0010)

Comment: Excellent! Works like a charm. I was looking for styling the XYCursor, but it should be the tooltip.